# Amcharts - How to open link in a new tab/window

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to make chart using amcharts. In that, I have the categories as links which I want to open in new tab/window. I added the following code which opens the link in a new tab/window but at same time opens the link in the same tab also. Please tell what I am doing wrong. I do not want to use Jquery and I am new to javascript.

This is the code which I added to the javascript for opening category link in new tab -

```
window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
```

This is the original AmCharts codepen - https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/50c8b6a103e7126fac91ce40000192be

This is the snippet -

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "titles": [{
    "text": "Open this demo in a separate window for links to work"
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 395,
    "url": "https://codepen.io"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  }],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20,
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "clickItem",
      "method": function(event) {
        window.location.href = event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url;
    window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
      }
    }]
  }

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.amcharts-axis-label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the line ..

```
 window.location.href = event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url;
```

.. from your **clickItem** listener.

This line instructs the browser to replace the current page location. Basically this line prevents the next line from executing.

This should work:

```
"listeners": [{
  "event": "clickItem",
  "method": function(event) {
    window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
  }
}]
```

It might not work in a Codepen environment, but it should work elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does not work. When I put code in my server, it opens link in a new tab but at the same time the link opens in the same window. That is the same problem I am facing at present.

Comment: Any field named "url" is automatically recognized by amCharts and will follow the default behavior. You might want to rename "url" to "website" to prevent amCharts from picking it up.

Comment: Apologise that there was a server problem. Your code is working. Accepting your answer. Please also give some appropriate documentation in your answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already answered - this was the top result in google when looking for a slightly modified solution when sourcing the URL from parsed dataset.

AmCharts documentation provides a [urlTarget attribute](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amgraph/#urlTarget_property) that you can use to use the same behaviour